# How to get a public key from a given private key with python module(fastecdsa)

Tags: python, ecdsa

I have a small python script that generates public key from private key the code can be seen below

```
import codecs
import ecdsa

private_key = "18e14a7b6a307f426a94f8114701e7c8e774e7f9a47e2c2035db29a206321725"

private_key_bytes = codecs.decode(private_key, 'hex')
public_key_raw = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(private_key_bytes, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).verifying_key
public_key_bytes = public_key_raw.to_string()
public_key_hex = codecs.encode(public_key_bytes, 'hex')
public_key = (b'04' + public_key_hex).decode("utf-8")
print(public_key)
```

But am looking for a script I can use to derive a public key from the private key useing the python module(fastecdsa), because the fastecdsa module I way faster.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.